# Simulation results don't match Synthesis schematics

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, xilinx, vivado

I've got a very simple circuit to update a register in my IP core.

```
input clk;
input rst;
input start;
input [31:0] ruleCount;

reg lastStart;
output reg [31:0] ruleCountReg;

always@(posedge clk)
    if (rst)
        lastStart <= 0;
    else
        lastStart <= start;

always@(posedge clk) 
    if (rst) begin
        ruleCountReg <= 0;
    end
    else if (start && !lastStart) begin
        ruleCountReg <= ruleCount;
    end
```

The goal here is to register `ruleCount` on the first cycle `start` is asserted (some other trasitions depend on this as well). So, I register `start` into `lastStart`, wait for the condition, and then act appropriately.

I'm using Vivado 2015.4 and <s>vSim</s> XSim, and a Kintex Ultrascale 060. After elaborate/synthesis, I get the following circuit schematics:

### [image: elaboration schematic]

[image: post-synthesis schematic]
My functional/RTL simulation matches what I'd expect. However, since the design wasn't functioning on the board, I opted to try a post-synthesis simulation, and got the following:
[image: post-synthesis simulation]
As shown, `start` gets raised by my testbench, and the output from the IBUF inserted by Vivado produces the same value. However, for reasons unknown, `lastStart` fails to capture the value on either of the two clock edges when `start` is high (t=35ns, t=45ns). Also, despite `start&&!lastStart` being high, `ruleCountReg` doesn't get updated either.

For comparison, here's the functional RTL simulation:
[image: functional RTL sim]
Is this a bug in Vivado? The Verilog is trivial, and it appears to be generating the correct schematics for the circuit, but could it be creating an incorrect netlist? Synthesis isn't producing any warnings that are relevant to these signals.

---

**Edit:** It appears as though xSim isn't updating any registers during the first 100ns of the simulation.

[image: timing sim (post-synth)]

Comment: Are you getting any timing violations in your sim? What happens if you slow the clock down?

Comment: My testbench is using a 100MHz clock, and I can P+R it on the board (as part of a bigger system) for >125MHz with no violations. I don't have any timing/implementation info for just the core, as it has too many I/Os to fit, and Vivado still lacks support for virtual pins.

Comment: @nguthrie: Alright, I'm confused - the post-synth functional  still does nothing when I use a clock period of 22ns or less (>45MHz). For periods of 24ns or higher (<42MHz), it works-ish; writes of 0 seem to be on-time, but writes of 1 appear to have very long setup-time requirements (at least 15ns). At >30ns (<33MHz) it works correctly.

Comment: My guess would be that you are missing some timing constraints so this is getting synthesized unconstrained. Are you sure that during the sim there is no timing check that fails?

Comment: No timing violations, and my design is constrained for a 5ns clock. I've even added a `set_max_delay` for the `start`->`lastStart` path of 2ns for either data edge with no change. If there's something obvious I'm missing, and someone could be specific about it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: One thing I am suspicious of is your post-synthesis waveforms appear to show 0 delay from `start` -> `start_IBUF` -> `start && !last_start`. If you zoom in on that edge is there actually a delay there? Is this sim back annotated with delays?

Comment: That's a functional model - the timing model has the same result, but does have the delays between. I've also discovered the problem isn't with the clock speed - it appears as though xSim won't update register values in the first 100ns (which explains why some of my slower clock rates worked; I didn't change the cycle counts, only the periods). After 100ns, everything appears to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Xilinx [UG900](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_1/ug900-vivado-logic-simulation.pdf#96) user guide, it's the intended behaviour.

> In post-synthesis and post-implementation simulations, the GSR (Global Set/Reset) signal
> is automatically asserted for the first 100 ns to simulate the reset
> that occurs after configuration.

So it's dumb, but intentional.